# Get Difference Between Dates

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I want to get the difference of days between two dates .I have tried DateDiff function in Sql but it is not working for the date-time values i.e

```
27/12/2013 8:53:00 PM
```

I tried the below query but it keeps on giving me this error

```
"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value "

declare @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime

select @StartDate = '27/12/2013 08:53:00.000',@EndDate='10/04/2012 09:52:48.000'

SELECT DATEDIFF(day,@StartDate,@EndDate) AS DiffDate
```

Any Help? Thanks In Advance

Comment: Your statement will tell you the difference in days. What exactly is it you're trying to get?

Comment: The term "is not working" is too vague to allow anyone to help you.  What happened when you ran that code?

Comment: Let me guess - you're getting "Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value." because your system is expecting US date formats and you're entering UK style?

Comment: well how can i solve this error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Why you get that error: *"The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"* ?

The reason is explained [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx):

> Supported String Literal Formats for datetime
>
> Numeric [0]4/15/[19]96 -- (mdy), ..., 15/[0]4/[19]96 -- (dmy), ...
>
> Description The setting for SET DATEFORMAT determines how date values
>   are interpreted.

So, this string literal `27/12/2013 8:53:00 PM` will be interpreted as DATETIME value using DATEFORMAT setting.

Examples:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDateFormat NVARCHAR(3);
SELECT @CurrentDateFormat = s.date_format FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s WHERE s.session_id = @@SPID;

PRINT 'Test #1:'
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
DECLARE @a DATETIME;
SET @a = '27/12/2013 8:53:00 PM';
PRINT @a;
PRINT 'End of Test #1';

PRINT 'Test #2:'
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
DECLARE @b DATETIME;
SET @b = '27/12/2013 8:53:00 PM';
PRINT @b;
PRINT 'End of Test #2';

SET DATEFORMAT @CurrentDateFormat;
```

Output:

```
Test #1:
Dec 27 2013  8:53PM
End of Test #1

Test #2:
Msg 242, Level 16, State 3, Line 14
The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

End of Test #2
```

2) Solutions ? Use a string literal format which is **independent** of DATEFORMAT setting. You could find these formats on the same [web page](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx).

Example with ODBC format:

```
DECLARE @CurrentDateFormat NVARCHAR(3);
SELECT @CurrentDateFormat = s.date_format FROM sys.dm_exec_sessions s WHERE s.session_id = @@SPID;

PRINT 'Test #1:'
SET DATEFORMAT DMY;
DECLARE @a DATETIME;
SET @a = {ts '2013-12-27 16:53:00'};
PRINT @a;
PRINT 'End of Test #1';

PRINT 'Test #2:'
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
DECLARE @b DATETIME;
SET @b = {ts '2013-12-27 16:53:00'};
PRINT @b;
PRINT 'End of Test #2';

SET DATEFORMAT @CurrentDateFormat;
```

Output:

```
Test #1:
Dec 27 2013  4:53PM
End of Test #1

Test #2:
Dec 27 2013  4:53PM
End of Test #2
```

3) These formats determine only how [string literal] values are interpreted as `DATETIME` values. The internal format/representation is described [here](http://books.google.ro/books?id=B83dXtOATAQC&pg=PA162&lpg=PA162&dq=sql+server+datetime+internal+representation&source=bl&ots=zDrSjsPlIu&sig=Vzwe26I-KYGpkBPTuX1KgaSqj3w&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zzq_UsLyM6j8ywOw44KYDw&ved=0CG0Q6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=sql%20server%20datetime%20internal%20representation&f=false).

4)

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SELECT  @StartDate  = {ts '2013-12-27 08:53:00.000'}, 
        @EndDate    = {ts '2012-04-10 09:52:48.000'}
SELECT  DATEDIFF(day,@StartDate,@EndDate) AS DiffDat
```

Answer (score 0):

This works

```
    declare @StartDate datetime, @EndDate datetime

select @StartDate = 'dec 27 2013 08:53:00.000',@EndDate='apr 10 2012 09:52:48.000'

SELECT DATEDIFF(day,@StartDate,@EndDate) AS DiffDate
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
declare @dt as datetime2;
declare @s as varchar(25), @dtstring as varchar(30);

select @s = '27/12/2013 08:53:00.00';

select @dtstring = substring(@s, 7, 4) + '-' + 
substring(@s, 4, 2) + '-' + 
left(@s, 2) + ' ' + substring(@s, 12, 12);
select @dt = cast(@dtstring as datetime2(4));

select @s ori, @dtstring modified, @dt result;
```

The results are:

```
ori                         modified            result
27/12/2013 08:53:00.00  2013-12-27 08:53:00.00  2013-12-27 08:53:00.0000000
```

Do the same for both your strings.  By the way, in your question, your start date was later than your end date.  Not sure if that was your intent.